# How do add a carnival fair age sense in python only allowing 10 and above

Tags: python, input

```py
age = input("How old are you? (10 and above) >>> ")

if age.lower() == 9 ≤ 100:
    print("enter")

else:
    print("sorry little man")
```

Comment: it is not working

Answer (score 0):

```
age = input("How old are you? (10 and above) >>> ")

if 9 < int(age) <= 100: 
    print("enter")
else: 
    print("sorry little man")
```

Output:

```
How old are you? (10 and above) > 10
enter
```

Comment: Enter your age: 101 -> sorry little man  XD

Comment: @SembeiNorimaki doesn't seem logic, but that's what he provided in his example.